# How to sort by line length, then reverse alphabetically

Tags: regex, bash, sorting, sed

I have a large (600 odd) set of search and replace terms that I need to run as a sed script over some files. The problem is that the search terms are NOT orthogonal... but I think I can get away with it by sorting by line length (i.e. pull out the longest matches first, and then alphabetically within each length. So given an unsort set of:

```
aaba
aa
ab
abba
bab
aba
```

what I want is a sorted set such as:

```
abba
aaba
bab
aba
ab
aa
```

Is there a way of doing it by say prepending the line lenght and sorting by a field?

*For bonus marks :-) !!!
The search and replace is actually simply a case of replacing 
    term
with
    _term_
and the sed code I was going to use was 
s/term/_term_/g
How would I write the regex to avoid replacing terms already within _ pairs?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compact it all into one regexp:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(aaba\|aa\|abba\)/_\1_/g'
testing words aa, aaba, abba.
testing words _aa_, _aaba_, _abba_.
```

If I understand your question correctly, this will solve all your problems: No "double replacement" and always matching the longest word.

Comment: Shouldn't you still sort the items by length? Or will there be some kind of greedy match going on that will always match the longest possible string?

Comment: ... plus, that's a hell of a long line for 600 items ;-) but maybe I can split it into more lines...

Comment: No need for that: A regular expression will always find the longest match.

Comment: @Dycey: Yeah, that would be quite long. You could put the script in a file in that case and do `sed -f regexpfile`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in a one-line Perl script:

```
perl -e 'print sort { length $b<=>length $a || $b cmp $a } <>' input
```

Comment: Should probably change `$a cmp $b` to be `$b cmp $a`, since he wanted it in reverse order.

Comment: +1 Any task you might be using lots of shell scripting for can be done easier, shorter, and potentially clearer in Perl.

Comment: I find this clearer than the Python solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670397/_/1670454#1670454

Comment: I would probably write it: `perl -E'say for sort { length $b<=>length $a } grep chomp, <>' input`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{print length($1),$1}' file |sort -rn
4 abba
4 aaba
3 bab
3 aba
2 ab
2 aa
```

i leave you to try getting rid of the first column yourself

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe your stream through this kind of script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

all={}
for line in sys.stdin:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if len(line) in all:
        all[len(line)].append(line)
    else:
        all[len(line)]=[line]

for l in reversed(sorted(all)):
    print "\n".join(reversed(sorted(all[l])))
```

And for the bonus mark question : again, do it in python (unless there really is a reason not to, but I'd be pretty curious to know it)

Comment: Is that the shortest, or clearest way to do that sort, in Python?

Comment: maybe not ; this was my first thought.

Comment: Personally, this is a quick-and-dirty enough that I'd rather use a Perl one-liner than write an entire Python script. Though if you insist on Python, it might be cleaner (if less efficient) to just slurp the file, then sort it, then spit it back out.

Answer (score 0):

This will sort a file by line length, longest lines first:

```
cat file.txt | (while read LINE; do echo -e "${#LINE}\t$LINE"; done) | sort -rn | cut -f 2-
```

This will replace `term` with `_term_` but won't turn `_term_` into `__term__`:

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^_])term([^_]|$)/\1_term_\2/g'
sed -r -e 's/(^|[^_])term/\1_term_/g' -e 's/term([^_]|$)/_term_\1/g'
```

The first will work pretty well except it will miss out on `_term` and `term_`, mistakenly leaving those alone. Use the second if that's important. Here's my silly test case:

```
# echo here is _term_ and then a term you terminator haha _terminator and then _term_inator term_inator | sed -re 's/(^|[^_])term([^_]|$)/\1_term_\2/g'
here is _term_ and then a _term_ you _term_inator haha _terminator and then _term_inator term_inator
# echo here is _term_ and then a term you terminator haha _terminator and then _term_inator term_inator | sed -r -e 's/(^|[^_])term/\1_term_/g' -e 's/term([^_]|$)/_term_\1/g'
here is _term_ and then a _term_ you _term_inator haha __term_inator and then _term_inator _term__inator
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the sort by length first, then reverse alpha bit

```
for mask in `tr -c "\n" "." < $FILE | sort -ur`
do
    grep "^$mask$" $FILE | sort -r
done
```

The `tr` usage replaces each character in `$FILE` with a period - which matches any single character in `grep`.